# Not able to start "Forefront Identity Manager Service"

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint 2010 installed on my machine. For synchronizing user profiles I am trying to start "Forefront Identity Manager Service".

But, when I click on start, it says the following message:

> The Forefront Identity Manager Service
>   service on WINSP02 started and then
>   stopped. Some services stop
>   automatically if they are not in use
>   by other services or programs.

Can anyone please help me in starting this windows service?

**Update:** This is a SharePoint Single Server Farm and Forefront Identity Manager Service is running with a domain account who is farm administrator and local administrator.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to start those services manually - SharePoint will do everything itself when you start the User Profile Sync service in Central Administration as at that point it will configure a number of different things.

It can take a good 10 minutes to actually start up as there's a number of timer jobs that need to complete.

If it never starts up it's usually indicative of a an issue with the account set to use the service.

This [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx) covers everything I used to get mine running.